# how to catch and save data from external website in laravel

Tags: laravel

Im going to add payment online payment gateway to my site,

So I m in srilanka and here we use payhere payment gatway
here is link - https://www.payhere.lk/
- https://sandbox.payhere.lk

they send me some to me using **notify_url** so I need to store those dat in my table,
problem is they send those using with **$_POST**. so how I can catch those data and save in my table

2. Listening to Payment Notification
   As soon as the payment is processed, PayHere notifies the payment status to the notify_url you posted to the Checkout API as a server callback & redirects the customer back to your website to the return_url. Payment notification will contain the following data as POST params, so you need to host a script on your notify_url to fetch the following POST params & update your database accordingly.

POST params
merchant_id - PayHere Merchant ID of the merchant
order_id - Order ID sent by Merchant to Checkout page
payment_id - Unique Payment ID generated by PayHere for the processed payment
payhere_amount - Total Amount of the payment
payhere_currency - Currency code of the payment (LKR/USD/GBP/EUR/AUD)
status_code - Payment status code (2, 0, -1, -2, -3)
md5sig - Encrypted signature to verify the payment
custom_1 - Custom param 1 sent by merchant to Checkout page
custom_2 - Custom param 2 sent by merchant to Checkout page
method - Payment method selected by the customer. (VISA, MASTER, AMEX, EZCASH, MCASH, GENIE, VISHWA, PAYAPP, HNB, FRIMI)
status_message - Message received from payment gateway which the customer tried to pay

If the customer made the payment by VISA or MASTER credit/debit card, following parameters will also be available.
card_holder_name - Card Holder Name
card_no - Masked card number (Ex: ************4564)
card_expiry - Card expiry in format MMYY (Ex: 0122)
Payment Status Codes

2 - success
0 - pending
-1 - canceled
-2 - failed
-3 - chargedback
Please note that;

You cannot test the payment notification by print/echo methods since notify_url never loads to the browser as it's a server callback. You can only test it by updating your database upon fetching the notification.
You cannot test the payment notification on localhost. You need to submit a publically accessible IP or domain based URL as your notify_url for PayHere to directly notify your server.
No payment status parameters are passed to the return_url when redirecting the customer back to your website. You need to update your database upon fetching payment status by your script on notify_url & then show the payment status to your customer in the page on return_url by fetching the status from your database.

3. Verifying the Payment Status
   It is important to verify the Payment Notification before taking any actions on the payment response. You can do the verification using the md5sig checksum parameter that is generated & sent by PayHere along with the payment status params according to following logic.

md5sig = strtoupper (md5 ( merchant_id + order_id + payhere_amount + payhere_currency + status_code + strtoupper(md5(payhere_secret)) ) )
Once you receive the payment status params from PayHere, you can locally generate this checksum using the merchant_id, order_id, payhere_amount, payhere_currency & status_code sent by the payment notification and the payhere_secret you have locally (You can find your Merchant Secret in your PayHere Account's Settings page). Your locally generated checksum should equals to the md5sig sent by PayHere if the payment notification is valid.

Code Sample (PHP)
You can host this script at your notify_url.

```
<?php

$merchant_id         = $_POST['merchant_id'];
$order_id             = $_POST['order_id'];
$payhere_amount     = $_POST['payhere_amount'];
$payhere_currency    = $_POST['payhere_currency'];
$status_code         = $_POST['status_code'];
$md5sig                = $_POST['md5sig'];

$merchant_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // Replace with your Merchant Secret (Can be found on your PayHere account's Settings page)

$local_md5sig = strtoupper (md5 ( $merchant_id . $order_id . $payhere_amount . $payhere_currency . $status_code . strtoupper(md5($merchant_secret)) ) );

if (($local_md5sig === $md5sig) AND ($status_code == 2) ){
        //TODO: Update your database as payment success
}

?>
```

Comment: Well, did you setup a route in your laravel app which receives a POST with the data?

Comment: yes,  Route::POST('/notify', 'PaymentsController@Notify' )->name('notify');

Comment: How are they sending you the data. If they are directly sending it to your url, You will need to setup webhooks in order to receive incomming request.

Comment: Ok, so in your `Notify` function inside the PaymentsController you can simply retrieve all incoming data using the $request object: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: @DeepeshThapa how I can do that

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-webhook-client  here is the package